# How to sign a JApplet using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, japplet, signing

I made a JApplet that works fine in both eclipse and when I embed it in a website(have to add the site to exceptions in java). I'm currently experiencing a problem with the jar file being unsigned. I tried using keytool and jarsigner in command prompt, but it said that these commands don't exist. I have the keytool plugin for Eclipse.

How can I sign my jar file using eclipse so people don't have to add the site to exceptions in java in order to run it?